# Superset: Group By query in chart

Tags: sql, postgresql, apache-superset

[image]

I want to sum CN_NET_TOTAL and distinct by CN_Invoice_No and show it using a BigNumber chart

Comment: Hi there, please read this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: You can't add `GROUP BY`s to the metric definition, it should be a simple aggregation expression.

Comment: @BetoDealmeida Are there any workarounds to this? Can I add a custom metric/column in the tablemodelview section of superset?

Comment: If you edit the dataset (under Data -> Datasets) you can add new derived columns and metrics to it.

Comment: Also, its a single metric. What are you trying to achieve by doing a group by? Take a look at the query generated to get a sense of what logic you are creating.